# synchronize: launch_closure_by_value: an illegal memory access was encountered

Tags: thrust

As shown in the following code, I create a large vector X and copy its content to Y through a cpy_cpy operator. It runs okay one the length of X is smaller than 65536, but crashes when X is longer than that. The error message is:

```
synchronize: launch_closure_by_value: an illegal memory access was encountered.
```

I'm using CUDA v6.0 on a Nvidia GTX 680 card.

Can anyone help me with this? Many thanks!

```
const int num = 256*512; //256*512 crashes but 128*512 is okay!

uchar3* x_raw_ptr, y_raw_ptr;
cudaMalloc((void **) &x_raw_ptr, num * sizeof(uchar3));
cudaMalloc((void **) &y_raw_ptr, num * sizeof(uchar3));

thrust::device_ptr<uchar3> X_p( x_raw_ptr ); 
thrust::device_ptr<uchar3> Y_p( y_raw_ptr ); 

thrust::transform(X_p, X_p + num*sizeof(uchar3), thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),  Y_p, cpy_cpy );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the reason for the error myself.

```
X_p + num*sizeof(uchar3) -> X_p + num
```

Then everything looks all right now.
Thrust examples are here:
http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformations.html#gacbd546527729f24f27dc44e34a5b8f73

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `X.begin()` and `X.end()` to get iterators directly from the vectors? What possible purpose does using `device_ptr` serve (other than making it easy to make mistakes as you have done here)?

Comment: Well, I'm learning about how to use device_ptr and how to pass device_ptr to transform(). In my project, the device memory is allocated by opencv cuda::GpuMat matrix instead of device_vector. Here, I just use device_vector for allocating some memory for device_ptr. I've noticed that device_vector::begin() device_vector::end() always work.

Comment: Thank to talonmies, to avoid confusing others, I updated my post.